# grid a licious with ng-repeat in angularjs way

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<div id="container">
        <div ng-repeat="itm in items" class="item">
            <div>
                <span>{{itm.name}}</span>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="i in itm.grouped">
                       <span>{{i.spName}}</span> 
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

view compiled and appendto jqueryui tab so source code like this

```
<html><body>
 <div id="innerPageContent" ng-show='UI.showTabs'>
        <div id="tabs" tabs>
            <ul id="tabs_ul">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div></body></html>
```

call in controller

```
  $scope.$watch("items", function (newValue, oldValue, scope) { 
        $("#container").gridalicious({
            width: 250
        });
    });
```

script complete function runs but it seems the same nothing change
its not find dynamic content?

Comment: no sign of grid-a-licious here could you include a plnkr showing what you've tried?

Comment: where are you making a call to `.gridalicious()` ? check it here, may be you will get an idea on how to make a call to `.gridalicious()`,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21261515/ng-repeat-within-grid-a-licious-grid

Comment: is there any errors in console ? re-check if `gridalicious` lib is loaded or not in your page

Comment: its ok, i m done with it

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
App.directive('onLastRepeat', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last)
            setTimeout(function() {
                scope.$emit('onRepeatLast', element, attrs);
            }, 1);
    };
});
App.controller('someController', function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('onRepeatLast', function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $("#container").gridalicious({
            selector: ".item"
        });
    });
};
```

AND in HTML :

```
<div id="container">
    <div ng-repeat="itm in items" class="item" on-last-repeat>
         <div>
           <span>{{itm.name}}</span>
             <ul>
               <li ng-repeat="i in itm.grouped" >
                      <span>{{i.spName}}</span> 
                 </li>
         </ul>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

This works for me in my project, Basically you need to call **$("#container").gridalicious()**  when all element has been rended